# Verifying the Solution to a 2nd Order ODE/Finding $y''$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

> The original problem: Verify that $y=-\ln(\sec(x) + \tan(x))\cos(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation $y''+y=\tan(x)$.

I found $y'$ to be...
$y'= -(\cos(x)(\sec(x)\tan(x)+(\sec(x))^2)/(\sec(x)+\tan(x)))+(\sin(x)(\ln(\sec(x)+\tan(x))))$

I am not sure how to differentiate the first term in $y'$ and find $y''$.

I'm sorry if I didn't use proper formatting or something, this is my first time using this website and I really need some help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: your first derivative can be simplified into $$y'(x)=\ln  \left( {\frac {1+\sin \left( x \right) }{\cos \left( x \right) }}
 \right) \sin \left( x \right) -1
$$
and $$y''(x)={\frac {1}{\cos \left( x \right) } \left( \ln  \left( {\frac {1+\sin
 \left( x \right) }{\cos \left( x \right) }} \right)  \left( \cos
 \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}+\sin \left( x \right)  \right) }
$$